# How to change size and color of image UIButton?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the UIButton that I create, like this

```
        let btn = UIButton()
        view.addSubview(btn)
        btn.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 150, height: 150)
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
        btn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnDelete.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

the problem is that I see the star icon button, but I can't find a way to make it bigger and change the color of the star itself, currently it is blue, but I need it white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For make it bigger use below code to fill width and height u giving in `btn.frame` :

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
```

For make it change the color of icon use :

```
 btn.tintColor = .white
```